# Does a Typical DELL XPS Laptop Feed Enough Power Through its USB Ports to Keep an External HDD Running?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, recovery

I want to recover my files on my 2.5" 4TB HDD, because I have broken system files that keep me from booting in Windows 10. To do this I bought a SATA→USB adapter that includes both the power and data connections in a single wire. When I plug my HDD into a DELL XPS laptop, on any of its two USB ports, I can only see a greyed-out USB Drive in my file explorer. The disk manger displays a greyed out section for it with no information at all. Does this mean the laptop is not feeding enough power? Do any average computers feed enough power via USB to keep an HDD running, or am I doing all this in vain?
Thanks.

Comment: For 3.5" drives USB does not has enough power (theoretically an adapter using USB-PD could draw more power to even power such a large drive but I have not seen an USB SATA adapter with USB PD support yet). For smaller drives it should be enough if the port is USB 3.0 or newer (blue, red, yellow port color)

Comment: In addition to what @Robert said.. I have one enclosure that uses two USB ports to get enough power.  I have another external enclosure that uses an external power supply to power the drive.  You might as well *try it* and see what happens ;)  It will either work.. or it won't

Comment: If you have a powered USB hub, it might be worth trying that. *Caveat* 1. Going throuigh a hub might slow I/O.  2. Some hubs might not have enough power.